# Bootstrap Switch - ON state

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am using this [bootstrap switch library](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/).

I have a checkbox in my html. Now, it is always showing in the OFF state, even though its checked property is set to true when the document is loaded.

What do I need to do besides that?

**Edit** - What I understand is Switch is adding a container around input type checkbox field with class `bootstrap-switch-off` by default, irrespective of the value of checked attribute that goes by with the checkbox field.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my-custom" id="Switch" checked="true">
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are producing?

Comment: can you please show your javascript code?

Answer (score 13):

Remember that `checked` is a [boolean attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute), meaning it's presence alone determines whether it is applied. In HTML5, you can use the [empty attribute syntax](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2) as either `checked` or `checked=""`, but I would caution against using `checked="true"`, as it implies `checked="false"` would actually do something.  Whereas `checked='potato'` is equally valid.

The following code should initialize bootstrap switch with checkboxes defaulted on or off:

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="switch" checked /> <!-- on  -->
<input type="checkbox" class="switch" />         <!-- off -->
```

```
$("input.switch").bootstrapSwitch();
```

[image: screenshot]

#### Working Demo in Stack Snippets & [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/nn6dU/)

```js
$("input.switch").bootstrapSwitch();
```

```css
body { padding: 15px; }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/css/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div >
    <label for="chk1">Default On:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="chk1" checked />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="chk2">Default Off:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="chk2" />
</div>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [Bootstrap Switch Docs](https://bttstrp.github.io/bootstrap-switch/options.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue, and it wa s simple one at that.

I had to add 'event' to my handleChange function

```
handleChange: function (event, state) {
      console.log(state);
      this.setState({storyStatus: state});
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding "state" property in JQuery:

```
$("#is_demo").bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).